# find() in Parse.Cloud.beforeSave not working

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-server, before-save

I am having a problem while trying to write a beforeSave cloud function.
This is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave
('MyCollection', function(request, response)
 {
  console.log("Hello from beforeSave-0");

 var unitListQuery;
 unitListQuery = new Parse.Query("MyCollection");
 //unitListQuery.equalTo("orderKey",request.object.get("orderKey").toString());
 unitListQuery.equalTo("orderKey",request.object.orderKey);

 console.log("Hello from beforeSave-1");
 console.log("ROG:"+request.object.get("orderKey"));
 unitListQuery.find().then
 (function(resUnit) {// Mark-One.
  console.log("Hello from beforeSave");
  console.log(resUnit);
  if (resUnit.length) {
    //response.error("RECORD-EXISTS");
    response.success();
    console.log("false-success-RECORD-EXISTS");
  } else {
    response.success();
    console.log("success-success");
  }// Mark-Two.
}, function(error) {
  console.error("Did not find the thing (" + request.object.get("orderKey") + ").");
  console.log("error : " + error);
  //response.error(error);
  response.success();
  console.log("false-success");
  });
 });
```

My current issue is that the execution never gets into the part of the code where something is found.
That is between the lines marked: *Mark-One* and *Mark-Two*, even when I can check by hand that the record exists in MyCollection.

**What am I missing here? I hope someone can point me to something wrong.**

For information, here is the record found in the _SCHEMA collection for MyCollection.

```
{
    "_id": "MyCollection",
    "objectId": "string",
    "updatedAt": "date",
    "createdAt": "date",
    "orderKey": "string",
    .....
    "_metadata": {
        "class_permissions": {
            "find": {
                "*": true
            }
        },
        "indexes": {
            "_id_": {
                "_id": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're getting a timeout error from response.success/error never getting called? Or is it just not printing the logs?

Comment: I don't think it'll be it but you can try adding a return statement before unitListQuery.find()

Comment: beforeSave triggers also have a 3 second timeout, instead of the standard 15 seconds of cloud code. Is your collection massive and not indexed by orderKey? Maybe the query is just taking so long it times out before returning.

Comment: No, my collection is only at testing level and is very small. Beside all the return and trace statements I have tried in the code work. It is only that for some reason find() does not find what is there. There must be something wrong in the way I use it.

Comment: Do you have an ACL / CLP set up? If you don't have public find permissions on the class / object, you have to pass in either a user session for a user who does, or use `.find({useMasterKey:true});`

Comment: About an ACL / CLP set up, I have added (I edited the post) the record found in the _SCHEMA collection for MyCollection. Please take a look, but as far as I can tell, there are public find permissions on the class. Let me know if you see something wrong.

Comment: How about the ACLs on the individual objects? Try just adding the useMasterKey option, then ACL / CLP doesn't matter. And you'll also know that it was a permission problem.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up by solving the problem, after enough trials. But how do you set up ACLs on the individual objects? I don't think I know how to do that.

Comment: Objects have a dedicated method to getting / setting the ACL, and then the ACL has its own methods to set read/write permissions for various roles.  There is some information in the parse-server guide on this. You can also use pointer permissions on the class level, which is really handy if you have an object that is "owned" by a particular user. Instead of modifying the ACL of each object, you set the user on the object and grant that field pointer permissions, and you're good to go. I.e. for a post/comment, you could give the user write permissions and public only has read permissions.